# iOS exception on custom cell of collection view

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I have an array with values paths of images and I want to display those images dynamically in `collection view` cell. But I am getting an exception.

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    data=[MyDatabase new];
    imagearray=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_url FROM interior":@"pic_url"];


    gallerycollection.dataSource=self;
    [[self gallerycollection]setDelegate:self];
    gallerycollection.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    customcell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // [[cell nyimage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    recipeImageView.image=[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

and I am getting exception

```
2013-03-13 11:22:30.662 Home[3371:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[customcell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9f7e410
```

---

@ Mithun MP: these are my database files

```
MyDatabase.h

#import "FMDatabase.h"
@interface MyDatabase : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *databaseName,*databasePath;
-(NSMutableArray *) OpenMyDatabase: (NSString *) query: (NSString *) column;
-(FMDatabase *)openDatabase: (NSString *)databasename;
-(NSMutableArray *) storeDatabaseColumnInArray: (FMDatabase *) database: (NSString *) sqlStatement: (NSString *) columnName;
@end


MyDatabase.m

#import "MyDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"




@implementation MyDatabase



-(NSMutableArray *)OpenMyDatabase: (NSString *)query: (NSString *)column
{
    //store the database name here
    self.databaseName=@"App_Database.sqlite";

    //get the reference of the database to be stored in device or emulator
    FMDatabase *database=[self openDatabase: self.databaseName];

    //open the database
    [database open];

    //fetch a collumn from database and store it in array
   // NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: @"select id from kas":@"id"];
    NSArray *nsarr= [self storeDatabaseColumnInArray: database: query: column];

    //close the database
    [database close];
    return nsarr;
}


- (FMDatabase *)openDatabase: (NSString *)databasename
{

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documents_dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *db_path = [documents_dir stringByAppendingPathComponent: databasename ];
    NSString *template_path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: databasename];

    if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:db_path])
        [fm copyItemAtPath:template_path toPath:db_path error:nil];
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:db_path];
    if (![db open])
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
    return db;
}
-(void) createAndCheckDatabase
{
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath];
    NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName ];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:nil];

}

-(NSMutableArray *) storeDatabaseColumnInArray : (FMDatabase *) database: (NSString *) sqlStatement: (NSString *) columnName
{

    NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];
    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery: sqlStatement];

    while([results next]) {

        NSString *rowValue = [results stringForColumn:columnName];

        [mutablearray addObject:results];
         NSLog(@"row value %@",rowValue);
    }

    //convert the nsmutable array to nsarray


    NSMutableArray *temparr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutablearray];
       return temparr;


}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because of this line:

```
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

I think you are setting the tag to the custom cell not to the image view.

Comment: thanks dude....u were right. i have tried that but am getting another exception now,                                                         -[FMResultSet _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9f7bb30
2013-03-13 11:42:21.330 Home[3565:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FMResultSet _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @user2147631: what is the content of imageArray ? I think it is an object of `FMResultSet` class, If I'm correct then issue is "you are setting the object of FMResultSet class to imageview, not an image"

Comment: imagearray contains image names which are retrieved from database column. what should i supposed to do now ?

Comment: @user2147631: can you `NSLog(@"%@",imageArray);` in viewDidLoad and paste the result here ?

Comment: after NSLog(@"%@",imageArray); the output is <FMResultSet: 0xab68b90>

Comment: @user2147631: that is what I said. The array contains an object of `FMResultSet` not an Image. Please check your db method and also you can't assign a NSString (image name) to image property. for that you can use:`imageNamed:` class method

Comment: what is -[FMResultSet length]:  exception ? which i am getting right now ?

Comment: @user2147631: I think you are using something like: ` recipeImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"%@",[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row]];` . If I'm correct, then I already said that you are getting an object of FMResultSet in the array not the image name or a NSString object

Comment: @ Mithun MP: yess correct. please tell me what should I do den ? any idea ?

Comment: @user2147631: if you can give me your team viewer Id or Pwd I can check the code

Comment: i dnt have teamviewer here . should i place whole code here ?

Comment: @user2147631 Please put it on paste bin. I only need to check your database code, which gives you the imageArray

Comment: @ Mithun MP: i've edited question and pasted code of database files there

Comment: @user2147631: Instead of `[mutablearray addObject:results];` in `storeDatabaseColumnInArray` method , write `[mutablearray addObject:rowValue];`

Comment: @user2147631: with pleasure :)